# Hibernate annotation @Where with parameter

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I currently have this class Product, annotated this way (I´m using soft delete):

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE products SET active = '0' WHERE id_product = ? and last_modification_date = ?")
@Where(clause = "active = '1'" )
@Entity
@Table(name = "products ")
public class Product {
  .....
}
```

What I want if to FILTER the beans (products), using the @Where clause, so that one user can only see the products from it own company. The company ID is in the session, and since the @SQLDelete receives parameters, I wanted to do something like:

```
@Where(clause = "active = '1' and id_company = ?" )
```

so that i can filter ALL the tables to fetch results according each user, without having to edit all the queries in the system. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Any help will be very aprecciated. 
Also, let me know if more info is needed to understand the problem.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Sorry @danm.cc, I gave up on soft delete. Too many complications (unique won´t work, cascades not allways behaving correct) so now I'm doing it by custom criteria.

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways of doing this in hibernate,

```
String hql = "from Stock s where s.stockCode = :stockCode";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setString("stockCode", "7277")
.list();
```

You can get more information from this link http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/

Comment: Hi @Luis Tellz! I was looking for something that don't relies on user code to ensure that no results form other companies are ever returned.<br> I though of something like replace all  `session.createCriteria(Class.getName()) ` for something like `session.createCompanyCriteria(Class.getName(), session) ` but the programmers can allways user the createCriteria method.